# Jenkins and Google Test (death test) using fork()

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, fork, googletest

we use Jenkins and Google Test for our project.

I wrote a GTest death test (EXPECT_EXIT) for our code.
It forks the code which is tested and captures its return code.
My tested code either terminates with signal 6 or with exit code 0.
Running the test on my local machine works out fine, it captures the code correctly.

Jenkins on the other hand probably does not fork()? The unit test terminates with signal 6 and the build fails.

Any ideas how this problem can be solved?

Comment: no idea why jenkins might cause fork to fail :(